# Nunit testcase can't be run with dll production environment with error of: An exception was thrown while loading the test

Tags: c#, nunit

I have some testcase are running with nunit in C#, it can run successful from local dev environment. But after moved to production environment, running with dll files only, it will fail with below error:

An exception was thrown while loading the test.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'nunit.framework, Version=3.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb'
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
at NUnit.Framework.Extensions.GetAttributes[T](ICustomAttributeProvider attributeProvider, Boolean inherit)
at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.BuildFrom(ITypeInfo typeInfo, IPreFilter filter, ITestFixtureData testFixtureData)
at NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute.d__47.MoveNext()
at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.DefaultSuiteBuilder.BuildFrom(ITypeInfo typeInfo, IPreFilter filter)

But actually all the reference for nunit.framework are using 3.11, so don't know why this is happen, can anyone help?

Really appreciate for your help!

How to run the C# test case with dll files only?
Which configuration will it find?